# Reset print function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started looking into the Python and need help on this.

In the shell I did

```
>>> print = 1
```

Now when I tried to print anything like

```
>>> print ("hello")
```

I am getting `"TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`, obviously because print in now a int

I am able to figure out that if I restart the shell, print starts working fine again.

What I want to know that how can I reset the `print` to its original state i.e. print to console without restarting the shell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You created a global that *masks* the built-in name. Use `del` to remove the new global; Python will then find the built-in again:

```
del print
```

Python looks for `print` through the current scope (in functions that includes locals and any parent scopes), then globals, then the [built-in namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), and it is in the latter that the `print()` function lives.

Answer (score 6):

You have "masked" the builtin `print` function by creating a variable with the same name. You could do one of three things:

1. Quit python and restart it. This is guaranteed to work. :-)
2. Delete the variable you created, as suggested by @MartijnPieters.
3. Change the new variable to refer to the `builtins.print` function.

For the last option, you'll need to `import builtins`.

```
>>> print = 1
>>> print("Hello")
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

>>> import builtins
>>> dir(builtins)
>>> ['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 
...
'print',
...
'tuple', 'type', 'vars', 'zip']

>>> print=builtins.print
>>> print("Hello")
>>> Hello
```

Comment: The last option still leaves a global in place, so `print` still masks the built-in `print`. They just happen to be bound to the same object.

Comment: Yeah, but it's a great chance to teach people about `builtins`!